# SEO Ranking for a website under DDOS attack

Tags: seo, ddos

Our website was under a DDOS attack and the attacker demanding $5000 to stop it. Under this condition, we have blocked all the traffic from outside India. Our customers are from ONLY India and we target only the Indian market.

As we have blocked the traffic from other countries, What is the possibility of losing our traffic and ranking in SEO?
Kindly update us, If we can get some authentic reply from someone.

Or How do we handle this situation in the correct way?

The same question was been raised in google community but unfortunately failed to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google (through their Googlebot) will crawl and index your website from their server's in California, USA - this means that if you are blocking ALL traffic from outside India, you are now invisible to Google and your rankings (your whole website, actually) will disappear completely from Google.

You should exclude Googlebot (and all other [Google crawlers](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en)) from your filter to avoid this.